# Magento 2 : Auto-deleting module files and theme files?

Tags: module, theme, magento2.4.6

I'm still pretty new to Magento but have been editing some code for modules and themes today and whilst making the edits all the files relating to a module and/or theme have been completely removed. (once for a module and the other time a theme)

I've never seen anything so odd before and I was wondering if anyone had come across this before or why it happens or whether I have some kind of intrusion or not.

It certainly doesn't seem like this behaviour should be normal. I can reupload the files and it comes back again however I am really curious.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Generally this can't happen into magento. Can you specify which file you are editing?